# Find slope of tangent line

Tags: tangent-line, slope

Find slope of the tangent line $$g(x)={5\over \sqrt{x}}$$ at x=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Following up on your answer, simply factor out the 5 from the numerator then apply Vivek's hint.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply differentiate your function $g(x)$:
$$g(x)=5x^{-1/2}$$
Now, use the fact that:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$
To obtain an expression for $g'(x)$ and then find $g'(9)$ (substitute $x=9$) to give you the slope.